# Docking In Maya 2016

Tags: maya

I accidentally undocked the status line and shelf tabs and can't get them attached to the main window the way they were. I can get them to go to the side of the main animation window, but not on top like they were before. I tired reverting settings and such but that doesn't work.

Comment: Try posting in cgtalk.com, programmers won't be of much help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you cannot drop them on the top because there is no longer anything there to drop onto in that panel zone.

You can try right clicking over the double dotted line above one of the other panels and see if toggling the interface items there (which include the shelf and status line) brings the items back.

You can also change the window settings *programmatically!* by editing the **windowPrefs.mel** file located in 
"User/Documents/maya/*maya version*/prefs".

Finally you can try changing the user preferences (click the little icon of a guy with a gear on its back left of the timeline or menu: Windows>Settings/Preferences>Preferences) where under "UI Elements" the same toggles are available, as well as opening files without using saved layout settings, etc...